# Do Kaladesh Dwarves get +4 in Constitution?

Tags: dnd-5e, ability-scores, dwarf

Sorry if this is a dumb question, but I read that that dwarves in general get a +2 in Constitution, and under the Kaladesh subrace, it doesn't just say "your Wisdom score increases by 1", it says "Your Constitution score increases by 2, and your Wisdom score increases by 1".

Is this a typo, or is this implying that the base race and subrace both stack to a total of +4 Constitution?

I'm just confused because I've never seen a subrace text reiterate the initial bonus again, and I figured it must have been a mistake.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take the [tour] when you get the chance. It's important to remember that there are thousands of RPGs out there; can you tell us which game & edition you're asking about?

Comment: What game and edition are you asking about? Please include a tag to indicate this. There are thousands of RPGs and we can’t provide an answer without knowing which one the question is about.

Comment: Pretty sure that there's only one possible option for the game, and that's DnD 5e, because that's the only game that has "Kaladesh", dwarves, and Constitution and Wisdom scores.

Comment: @nick012000 Settings are easily adapted, and dwarf, constitution, and wisdom are definitely not unique to 5th Edition.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Google knows only one place with both the sentence *"Your Constitution score increases by 2, and your Wisdom score increases by 1"* and words Kaladesh and Dwarf. It's https://media.wizards.com/2017/downloads/magic/Plane-Shift_Kaladesh.pdf and pages that quote it.

Comment: @Mołot I find 16 results for that query—most referencing _Plane-Shift: Kaladesh_, but not all of them cite their sources, and one I am not actually sure _is_ 5e, since it is mostly story and description and the limited mechanical details provided without context. But that’s not the point: the point is that we have a rule about these things, as you well know. That rule is being reconsidered, but it has not been yet. For now, it does not matter how much evidence you have: the rule is the OP has to clarify, not anyone else.

Comment: Voting to reopen because the consensus in the "Don't revisit the system" Meta thread seems to be to drop the rule.

Comment: @nick012000 Please ad the relevant version then. As is, I have to deny.

Comment: Without a clear quote from a source to identify, I don't think this should reopen.

Answer (score 6):

### Kaladesh's Dwarf isn't a subrace.

Nothing in the Plane Shift: Kaladesh document states that it's a subrace, they just talk about the race of dwarves on Kaladesh. This does seem unintuitive - the entire system of subraces exists so that you don't have to completely redefine a dwarf every time you create a variation on it - but the Plane Shift series was released in the early days of D&D, and perhaps things weren't entirely settled.

If you want proof of this, the ASI is actually the wrong place to look. Instead, look at the traits Age, Alignment, Size, Speed, Darkvision, Dwarven Resilience and Languages. These are all duplicated over both the PHB dwarf race and the Kaladesh dwarf, most of them being word-for-word identical. This would be nonsensical for a subrace, and essential for a race.